# jQuery button state active

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

How can I make a jQuery UI button maintain `ui-state-active`?

I have a button, that I want to be a toggle button. So when I activate it should stay active.

Currently if I set `ui-state-active` on a button it will get removed if I hover over it.

The markup for the button is just:

```
this.button = $('<div>')
    .html(this.text)
    .addClass(this.options.baseClass)
    .attr('title', this.getTitle())
    .click(this.click.bind(this))
    .button();
```

And the button must be a `div`, it can't be a `checkbox`.

???

Comment: wonder why not use the [buttons javascript from Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#buttons) that has all this included already.

Comment: @balexandre because I am using jQuery UI. Why not just rewrite everything while I am at it?

Comment: you can always just use `buttons.js` for this ... and no need to be aggressive, a comment is just an idea, no need to be rude.

Comment: @balexandre sorry for being rude. Button.js will conflict with jQuery UI button, and it does not support the jQuery UI theme framework.

Comment: jQuery UI supports toggle buttons. See http://jqueryui.com/button/#checkbox

Comment: @ori I can't use a checkbox.

Comment: it would help if you clarified what your purpose is with keeping ui-state-active: is it merely for styling/CSS purpose, or do you have some other code relying on a class selector? Like Michael Robinson suggests in his answer, I'd go for some custom class name that you toggle in the click handler like this.button.toggleClass('someClass').

Comment: @LaurentS It is for styling, as the button is a toggle button. I could use another class, but then I would either have to duplicate the jQuery UI theme styles, or modify the theme itself. Which mean that the widget would no long be theme roller compatible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Simple workaround

Another suggestion is to use `ui-state-highlight` instead.

### Manually handle hover

Aside from using a `checkbox` & `label` combination instead of a `div`, the only workaround I've used is to unbind `mouseover` & `mouseout` from the button post-initialization, then binding my own `mouseover`/`mouseout` function to the button that handles the toggling of `ui-state-hover` myself.

```
this.button = $('<div>')
    .html(this.text)
    .addClass(this.options.baseClass)
    .attr('title', this.getTitle())
    .click(this.click.bind(this))
    .button()
    .unbind('mouseover mouseout hover')
    .bind('mouseover', function() {
        $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover');
    }).
    bind('mouseout', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover');
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Using ui-state-highlight would be easy for you. Instead maintaining the state of ui-state-active, you can assign the above markup to this ui-state-highlight.

Answer (score 0):

Not strictly legal, but try adding a `type="checkbox"` attribute to your div or perhaps do `this.button.type = 'checkbox'` The button will still be a `div`, but you might get the effect you want.

The other day I was doing some soul searching, tracking down a similar problem, and ended up at the following "offending" lines in jQuery UI:

```
    var self = this,
        options = this.options,
        toggleButton = this.type === "checkbox" || this.type === "radio",
        hoverClass = "ui-state-hover" + ( !toggleButton ? " ui-state-active" : "" ),
        focusClass = "ui-state-focus";
```

A bit after that there is some code that removes the `hoverClass` from the button on `mouseout`. Essentially you need to force `toggleButton` true.

***This is 10 out of 10 hackery, though. Use at your own risk.***

Answer (score 0):

I suppose if styling is the issue, what you can do is build the button manually, something like:

```
this.button = $('<div>')
    .addClass(this.options.baseClass)
    .addClass("ui-state-default ui-button ui-button-text-only ui-corner-all")
    .attr('title', this.getTitle())
    .append('<span class="ui-button-text">button text</span>')
    .hover(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('ui-state-hover');
    })
    .click( function() {
        this.toggleClass('ui-state-active');
        // anything else you need
    };
```

This makes it themeroller compatible (the classes don't change between themes). Of course you can replace "ui-button-text-only" with the icon version if you prefer... (I've used this on my own projects, it does the trick)